# Disconnected pieces in SO(n,m) and O(n,m) : count and parametrize

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, differential-geometry, finite-groups, lie-groups

Based on a lecture in the relativistic physics, I reach a conclusion that

- special orthogonal group SO(3,1) has two disconnected pieces. Yes or no? How do we parametrize the two disconnected pieces in full?

Furthermore,  special orthogonal group SO(n,m) has two disconnected pieces. Yes or no? How do we parametrize the two disconnected pieces ?

- orthogonal group O(3,1) has four disconnected pieces. Yes or no? How do we parametrize the four disconnected pieces in full?

Furthermore, orthogonal group O(n,m) has four disconnected pieces. Yes or no? How do we parametrize the four disconnected pieces ?

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article on the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) answer your question?

Comment: thanks --There are also issues SO(n,m) and O(n,m) -- and How do we parametrize the disconnected pieces in full?